# How can I find the positions of nodes in Dash/Cytoscape after the user moved them?

Tags: cytoscape.js, plotly-dash

I'm using Cytoscape in Plotly/Dash and I'm creating a simple graph. I then move a few nodes around to various positions. I am then trying to read the these positions in a Dash callback - I've tried:

- `State("cytoscape-graph", "stylesheets")`
- `State("cytoscape-graph", "layout")`
- `State("cytoscape-graph", "elements")`
- More or less anything I could find [in the docs here](https://dash.plot.ly/cytoscape/reference/)

Example nodes:

```
{'data': {'id': 'id0', 'label': 'Node 0'}, 'position': {'x': 50, 'y': 150}},
         {'data': {'id': 'node1', 'label': 'Node 1'}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 100}},
         {'data': {'id': 'node2', 'label': 'Node 2'}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}},
         {'data': {'source': 'node0', 'target': 'node1', 'id': '4300352b-9533-4fef-90ec-7a5cbff1f8c4'}},
         {'data': {'source': 'node1', 'target': 'node2', 'id': '33d4c841-bcfc-4a07-ac56-90d36982601a'}},
}
```

The above either return `None`, anything else that doesn't contain relevant information, or the initial node positions. I tried looking at the rendered source code but I can't seem to find information there; only a `canvas` element. I'd appreciate pointers even for the Javascript backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
It seems that Dash does not allow direct access to ...elements().jsons() so the answer to the question is that it's probably not possible to do purely with Dash. You will probably have to write a callback for every time a node is clicked to run this in javascript and output it to some hidden div, and then read it in Dash. 
~ Credit goes to OP for answering this question

This is, as pointed out in this [section](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.jsons) of the documentation, easily achievable. The method `cy.elements()/nodes()/edges().jsons()` gets an array of the plain JavaScript object representation of all specified elements in the collection.

```js
var json;
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "100px",
        shape: "rectangle",
        "background-color": "data(faveColor)"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "control-point-step-size": 40,
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "Top",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "yes",
          faveColor: "#37a32d"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "no",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Third",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Fourth",
          faveColor: "#56a9f7"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "yes"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "no"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "no",
          target: "Third"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Third",
          target: "Fourth"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Fourth",
          target: "Third"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  layout: {
    name: "dagre"
  }
}));
cy.ready(function() {
  console.log('Nodes:', cy.nodes().jsons());
  console.log('Edges:', cy.edges().jsons());
  console.log('Elements:', cy.elements().jsons());
});

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  json = cy.json();
});
document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('click', function() {
  cy.json(json);
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- cyposcape dagre -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <b id="save" style="cursor: pointer; color: darksalmon">Save graph</b> / <b id="load" style="cursor: pointer; color: darkmagenta">Load graph</b>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems that Dash does not allow direct access to `...elements().jsons()` so the answer to the question is that it's probably not possible to do purely with Dash. I guess I will probably have to write a callback for every time a node is clicked to run this in javascript and output it to some hidden div, and then read it in Dash. I'm marking this as accepted, and thanks once again for giving me the idea. Please also edit the answer so people can see that it can't be done Dash-only.